# Huge empty space in table header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table. At the moment it only has 2 headers - one with a table and one with a graph. The first header has a huge empty space as you can see in the picture below:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<table id="patient-table">
  <th>
    <table id="data-table">
      <tr>...</tr>
    </table>
  </th>
  <th>
      <ngx-charts-polar-chart [view]="view" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="patientService.patientLevel3.latestReading" [gradient]="gradient"
        [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend" legendTitle="" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
        [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [autoScale]="autoScale">
      </ngx-charts-polar-chart>
  </th>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
#data-table{
 border-collapse: collapse;
 font-size: 14px;
}

#data-table th, tr, td{
 border: 1px solid black;
}

#patient-table{
 clear: both;
}
```

How do I move the table to the top of its cell to get rid of that space?

Answer (score 0):

You've added content into the table header element. This should only be used for column headings. Move the content to the table rows instead. Try

```
<table id="patient-table">
  <th>
      Table
  </th>
  <th>
      Chart
  </th>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table id="data-table">
      <tr>...</tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <ngx-charts-polar-chart [view]="view" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="patientService.patientLevel3.latestReading" [gradient]="gradient"
        [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend" legendTitle="" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
        [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [autoScale]="autoScale">
      </ngx-charts-polar-chart>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I solved it by putting my <th>'s in a <tr> and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually not a good idea to use tables for layout (see [Why not use tables for layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/84986/2714730)).

You can probably just throw them in a couple `div`s instead (there are many ways to accomplish the layout):

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <table><!-- your data table here --></table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ngx-charts-polar-chart [view]="view" [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="patientService.patientLevel3.latestReading" [gradient]="gradient"
        [xAxis]="showXAxis" [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend" legendTitle="" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
        [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" [autoScale]="autoScale">
    </ngx-charts-polar-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Alternatively you can just float the 2 interior `div`s left and right respectively, since flexbox layout [isn't compatible in some browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know tables were bad to use for layout. Will try out your solutions instead!